# javascript's object property member change so strangely

Tags: javascript

```
var obj = {name:"小明"};
console.log("obj1",obj);
// 1. {name:"小明",age:10}
obj.age = 10;
console.log("obj2",obj);
// 2. {name:"小明",age:10}
```

**why** does the browser console display  the result at the first? I think the reuslt should be an unchanged object `{name:"小明"}`.Now ,I have a headache about it . appreciate your response.

Comment: Depending on the browser, the console shows a live link to the object. If you don't expand the object within the console until after the line that adds the `.age` property runs then when you do expand you'll see that property. Is that what you mean? One way to avoid this is to use `console.log("obj1", JSON.stringify(obj))`, to log a snapshot of the object at that moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on the browser. If I recall correctly, chrome logs an unchanging object whereas firefox logs a changing one. Either way, `obj.age` will be undefined until you define it.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are seeing/expanding the object after adding the new property `age`.
Initially the object has only one property but by the time you are inspecting it , a new key will be added to the object

[image]

Another way is to verify using `hasOwnProperty`. In below snippet the first console.log statement won't be executed since the object does not have the key age

```js
var obj = {
  name: "小明"
};
if (obj.hasOwnProperty('age')) {
  console.log("obj1", obj);
}
obj.age = 10;
console.log("obj2", obj);
```

Comment: got it . And different browsers will log different results.

Answer (score 0):

When you expand the object the values displayed in the console are evaluated at runtime.

Tooltip in Chrome console explaining that values are evaluated at runtime:

[image: Tooltip in Chrome console explaining that values are evaluated at runtime]

You could try [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) to print the current value to the console.

e.g.

```
console.log("obj1", JSON.stringify(obj));
```

Comment: got it , appreciate it